# Linq: group objects and remove duplicate elements from their child elements

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

So I have this class structure:

```
public class ObjectCode
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class Configuration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ObjectCode> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving a list of `Configuration` from multiple providers. My problem is that I don't know how to group these objects by Id and put the distinct `ObjectCode` objects from all the `Configuration` objects in the resulting entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) inside each group in `GroupBy`:

```
var res = congigs
    .GroupBy(c => new {c.Id, c.Name})
    .Select(g =>
        new Configuration {
            Id = g.Key.Id
        ,   Name = g.Key.Name
        ,   Objects = g
               .SelectMany(c => c.Objects)
               .GroupBy(c => c.Code)
               .Select(gg => gg.First())
        }
    ).ToList();
```

The above assumes that `Config` objects with the same `Id` also have identical `Name`s.

Comment: Yes, that was the answer I was looking for. I will accept it as soon I am allowed. Thank you.